# Store AJAX Search results with Vue and Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js

My goal is to have two input fields where I can type the three-letter code of an airport and AJAX would run a query to check if this airport exists in the database. If it does, it will return the name of this airport under the input field.

I managed to get the first input to work, however, I have a second input where I want to search for a second airport but whenever I write an airport code in this second field the result of the first search gets overwritten.

Below is the Vue component that contains the two input fields. Do you know what is the right way to get two results using the same `airportSearch()` method?

```
<template>
    <div class="pairing-search">
        <div class="airport-input">
            <input type="text" v-model="From" @keyup="airportSearch">
            <ul v-if="Airports.length > 0">
                <li v-for="airport in Airports" :key="airport.id">{{ airport.name }}&nbsp;({{ airport.gps_code }})</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="airport-input">
            <input type="text" v-model="To" @keyup="airportSearch">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "PairingSearch",
        data() {
            return {
                From: null,
                To: null,
                Airports: []
            };
        },
        methods: {
            airportSearch() {
                axios.get('/searchairport', {
                    params: { keyword: this.From }
                })
                .then(res => this.Airports = res.data)
                .catch(error => {});
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry I am not farmiliar with vue,but after I read the document,you could do like this.use parameter to split which input fire the event.then set different element value.

```html
<template>
    <div class="pairing-search">

        <div class="airport-input">
            <input type="text" v-model="From" @keyup="airportSearch('first')">
            <ul v-if="Airports.length > 0">
                <li v-for="airport in Airports" :key="airport.id">{{ airport.name }}&nbsp;({{ airport.gps_code }})</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="airport-input">
            <input type="text" v-model="To" @keyup="airportSearch('second')">
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "PairingSearch",
    data() {
        return {
            From: null,
            To: null,
            Airports: []
        };
    },
    methods: {
        airportSearch(which) {
            axios.get('/searchairport', {
                    params: { keyword: this.From }
                })
                .then(function(res){
                    if(which=='first'){
                        this.Airports = res.data
                    }else if (which=='second'){
                        this.Airports2 = res.data
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {});
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```html
<template>
  <div class="pairing-search">
    <div class="airport-input">
      <input type="text" v-model="From" @keyup="airportSearch(true)" />
      <ul v-if="sourceAirports.length">
        <li v-for="airport in sourceAirports" :key="airport.id">
          {{ airport | formatName }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="airport-input">
      <input type="text" v-model="To" @keyup="airportSearch()" />
      <ul v-if="destAirports.length">
        <li v-for="airport in destAirports" :key="airport.id">
          {{ airport | formatName }})
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "PairingSearch",
  data() {
    return {
      From: null,
      To: null,
      sourceAirports: [],
      destAirports: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    airportSearch(isSource = false) {
      axios
        .get("/searchairport", {
          params: {
            keyword: isSource ? this.From : this.To
          }
        })
        .then(res => {
          if (isSource) this.sourceAirports = res.data;
          else this.destAirports = res.data;
        });
    }
  },
  filters: {
    formatName: function(airport) {
      return `${airport.name} (${airport.gpsCode})`;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Salvino,

The code you use makes sense to me. However it does not return any result, thus the sourceAirports and destAirports do not get populated with the results.

Comment: Hi @AlexandruAna extremely sorry! I have refactored + tested my code and updated my answer now.

Comment: PS: Please use camel casing for all variable names @AlexandruAna.